# show/hide div is opening all divs when button is clicked instead of just one

Tags: php, javascript, html, pdo, show-hide

I'm trying to use the show/hide on a div with buttons but it's opening all divs at once when the button is clicked here's the page i'm trying it out on [http://starsQA.com/jen-lilley-interviews](http://starsqa.com/jen-lilley-interviews)

here's the code:

```
<?php
    include("db_conn.php");
    $qry_string = "select * from questions WHERE starID = 8 && returned = 1 GROUP BY `reason` ORDER BY `edited` DESC, starID ASC, `reason`";
    $prep = $pdo_conn->prepare($qry_string);
    $prep->execute(array($starid));
    while ($row = $prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<button class='show_hide' id='tglbtn{$row['reason']}'>{$row['reason']}</button>";
//        echo "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
        echo "<div style='color:black;' class='slidingDiv' id='tgldiv{$row['reason']}'><b><u>{$row['reason']}</u></b><br><ol>";
        $qry_stringq = "select * from questions WHERE starID = 8 && returned = 1 && reason = '{$row['reason']}' ORDER BY starID ASC, `reason`";
        $prepq = $pdo_conn->prepare($qry_stringq);
        $prepq->execute(array($starid));
            echo "<ol style='margin:30px'>";
            while ($rowq = $prepq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo "<li><b>{$rowq['question']} - {$rowq['whoAsked']}</b><br>
                        {$rowq['response']}</li><br>";

            }
            echo "<ol'></div>";
        echo "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
     }
     echo "<br><br>";
    ?>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();


                    $no = $(this).attr('id').substring(6);

                    if($("#tgldiv" + $no).css("display") == "inline-block") {
                        $("#tgldiv" + $no).css("display", "none");
                        $(this).html($namearray[$no]);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#tgldiv" + $no).css("display", "inline-block");
                        $namearray[$no] = $(this).html();
                        $(this).html("hide");
                    }
                 });   
});

</script>
```

css:

```
            .slidingDiv {
    height:300px;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #3399FF;
}

.show_hide {
    display:none;
}
```

anyone got any ideas on how to fix this issue??? *FIXED*

also how do it stop the div's opening up while the page is loading/opening? *STILL NEEDS FIXING*

getting content to fix in each div would be great help too

Comment: You have 2 `$(".show_hide").click(function() {` click function in your javascript.

Comment: removed that and no change (took it out of the code above aswell)

Comment: which click function you removed?

Comment: i removed the 2nd one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `$(".slidingDiv")` is referencing all elements with the class of `slidingDiv`. What you need is context. You need the nearest element to your button. It looks like all your expanding divs are neighbours of your buttons, so you could use jQuerys [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) for this:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
   $(this).next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
});
```

*Also, please don't put spaces into your id attributes, it will break your page.*

Comment: whoops, that was rushed, try now

Comment: opening one now, do u know how to stop the div's opening up while the page is loading/opening?

Comment: exchange this: `echo "<div style='color:black;' class='slidingDiv' id='tgldiv{$row['reason']}'><b><u>{$row['reason']}</u></b><br><ol>";` with this `echo "<div style="color: black; display: none;" class='slidingDiv' id='tgldiv{$row['reason']}'><b><u>{$row['reason']}</u></b><br><ol>";`

Comment: thanks, I'll try that when I get in, do u know how to get content to fit in each div?

Comment: At the top of your page, in your header, you have `<style>` tag. On line twenty you've set `height:300px;`. Change that to `height:auto` and the height of the div will adapt :)

Comment: thanks oops my bad, I was trying to code it up quickly before I had to head out

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$("this").next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle(); // need target one .slidingDiv  
});
```

Comment: with that buttons don't click

Comment: buttons still not clicking